# How can I integrate WinSCP with BeyondTrust PowerBroker Password Safe?

Tags: unix, winscp

I am able to launch WinSCP application and able to pass the hostname as its parameters but failing to do the same for Username and Password. Below are the parameters which I have supplied.

```
-S %h -U %u -P %p
```

Instead of 'Retrieve Password', I am using 'Application Session' feature. It opens up WinSCP on that host but could not go past username and password which should be automatic. Like, when I use 'Open SSH', it opens up the Putty and automatically log on to that server.

**Update:**
[Image updated as per Mark's way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRrGI.jpg)

Comment: Are those even valid commandline switches for WinSCP ? AFAIK passing a username and password is done by setting a url such as `sftp://user:password@example.com/`

Comment: @HBrujin - Kindly see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

To pass hostname (I assume that's what you mean by `-S`), username and password on [WinSCP command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline), use [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url):

```
sftp://%u:%p@%h/
```

---

*WinSCP does not have `-S`, `-U` nor `-P` switches.*

Comment: I was passing these switches in Password Safe's configuration. -S is Session. I tried it your way but not getting it as %u has been read prior to the hostname - it is assuming %u as the hostname. It is working fine if I am running an SQL instance as an application. I have updated the questions with some snapshots. Kindly see.

Comment: Show us screenshots with my way. Screenshots with your way are useless, WinSCP does not understand those parameters.

Comment: I have updated the image your way.

Comment: Then it looks like the `%h` does not do what you think. Do you have a documentation for patterns that you can use in PowerBroker?

Comment: This is what it says in one of the example:
**To do this, set the parameters to:
*-S %h -d btu_hr_apps -U %u -P %p*;
At session connection time, the:
• %h is replaced by Password Safe with the name of the managed system
• %u is replaced by Password Safe with the username for the managed account
• %p is replaced by Password Safe with the managed password
Note: There are additional variables available, such as:
• %i ip address
• %t port number
• %d database or asset name**

Comment: What is "name of managed system"? Maybe you can try `%i` instead of `%h`.